# Keep cell reference when dragging down

Tags: excel-formula

Column A: Cost of an apple
Column B: Quantity of apples purchased
Column C: Total cost of apples purchased

Cell A2: $1.50
Cell B2: 3
Cell B3: 10
Cell B4: 15

C2 currently has the formula =A2*B2. How would I tweak the formula, so that when I drag down the formula to cells C3 and C4, A2 stays the same?

Comment: This question isn't about programming. Try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) and tag it `microsoft-excel`.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a specific cell reference value, use a `$` in front of the cell *and* row reference, so to the formula, that would be: `$A$2*B2`

Comment: Good answer, but it's important to know that using `$` in front of the column letter, locks the column reference when dragged. Using it in front of the row number locks the row. Using both locks both. In this case it would be `A$2*B2` or `$A$2*B2`

Comment: Thanks for tip, I've updated the answer. I don't use Excel very often, and I tend to forget about the row reference as well, until I need the same use myself at some later point.